# How to assert that an element value is of certain type?

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there a good way to assert that the value of the current element must be of a certain type (e.g. xs:integer), and thrown an exception if it's not? Using XSL 2.0

Answer (score 1):

**One can use the `f:type()` function of the [FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net) library to dynamically determine the type of a variable/value**.

Here is the test transformation in FXSL for `f:type()`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
 exclude-result-prefixes="f xs"
 >
  <xsl:import href="../f/func-type.xsl"/>

  <!-- To be applied on ../data/numList.xml -->

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    f:apply(f:typeConstructor(11),'03'): <xsl:value-of select="f:apply(f:typeConstructor(11),'03')"/>
    f:apply(f:typeConstructor('xxx'),'03'): <xsl:value-of select="f:apply(f:typeConstructor('xxx'),'03')"/>
    f:apply(f:typeConstructor(11),'03') gt 4: <xsl:value-of select="f:apply(f:typeConstructor(11),'03') gt 4"/>
    f:type(f:apply(f:typeConstructor(11),'03')): <xsl:value-of select="f:type(f:apply(f:typeConstructor(11),'03'))"/>
    f:type(f:apply(f:typeConstructor('string'), 3)): <xsl:value-of select="f:type(f:apply(f:typeConstructor('string'),'03'))"/>
<!--  Supported only by a SA Processor -->
    xs:token('abc') : <xsl:value-of  select="f:type(xs:token('abc'))"
       use-when="system-property('xsl:is-schema-aware')='yes'"/>

    -1 : <xsl:value-of select="f:type(-1)"/>
<!--  Supported only by a SA Processor -->
    xs:negativeInteger(-1) : <xsl:value-of select="f:type(xs:negativeInteger(-1))"
       use-when="system-property('xsl:is-schema-aware')='yes'" />
    xs:nonPositiveInteger(0) : <xsl:value-of select="f:type(xs:nonPositiveInteger(0))"
       use-when="system-property('xsl:is-schema-aware')='yes'" />

    0 : <xsl:value-of select="f:type(0)"/>
    3 : <xsl:value-of select="f:type(3)"/>
    3. : <xsl:value-of select="f:type(3.)"/>
    3.0E1 : <xsl:value-of select="f:type(3.0E1)"/>
    xs:float(3) : <xsl:value-of select="f:type(xs:float(3))"/>
<!--  Supported only by a SA Processor -->
    xs:positiveInteger(3) : <xsl:value-of select="f:type(xs:positiveInteger(3))"
       use-when="system-property('xsl:is-schema-aware')='yes'" />

   '3' : <xsl:value-of select="f:type('3')"/>
   (/*/*/text())[1] : <xsl:value-of select="f:type((/*/*/text())[1])"/>
   data((/*/*/text())[1]) : <xsl:value-of select="f:type(data((/*/*/text())[1]))"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on this XML document:**

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted, corect results are produced:**

```
    f:apply(f:typeConstructor(11),'03'): 3
    f:apply(f:typeConstructor('xxx'),'03'): 03
    f:apply(f:typeConstructor(11),'03') gt 4: false
    f:type(f:apply(f:typeConstructor(11),'03')): xs:integer
    f:type(f:apply(f:typeConstructor('string'), 3)): xs:string

    xs:token('abc') : xs:string

    -1 : xs:integer

    xs:negativeInteger(-1) : xs:integer
    xs:nonPositiveInteger(0) : xs:integer

    0 : xs:integer
    3 : xs:integer
    3. : xs:decimal
    3.0E1 : xs:double
    xs:float(3) : xs:float

    xs:positiveInteger(3) : xs:integer

   '3' : xs:string
   (/*/*/text())[1] : xml:node
   data((/*/*/text())[1]) : xs:string
```

**Explanation**:

`f:type()`, as can be seen from **[its source](http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/func-type.xsl?revision=1.12&view=markup)** uses internally the XPath 2.0 operator `instance of` and tests a value from a most common type to more specific types until it determines a specific type.

Answer (score 0):

In `XPath`, you can use `instance of` like this:

> 5 instance of xs:integer

This example returns true because the given value is an instance of the given type.

For additional information, you can check [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#doc-xpath-InstanceofExpr).

Answer (score 0):

With a schema aware XSLT 2.0 processor like the enterprise editions of Saxon 9 or like XmlPrime or AltovaXML you can use W3C XML schemas to validate your input documents when processing them with XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `cast as` operator, e.g.

`'5' cast as xs:integer` returns 5

`'foo' cast as xs:integer` throws `Cannot convert string "d" to an integer` using Saxon.

If you want to throw your own error you can use `castable as`, e.g.

```
if (not('foo' castable as xs:integer)) then
   error((), 'bad')
```